# C# Transpor Colunas em linhas

Tags: c#, lista

Em C# - Linq: Tenho uma collecion de List de objetos:

Campo 1 |
    Campo 2 | 
    Campo 3 |
    Campo 4 |
    Campo 5 |
    
    Teste   |
    15 |
    20 |
    45 |
    52 |

Preciso transpor essa linha de uma coleção para um List de inteiros 
  15 
  20 
  45 
  52

Alguém poderia de ajudar?

Preciso de uma versão bem otimizada para isso, sem a carga de precisar iterar algo.

Obrigado.

---

Para ficar mais claro irei postar o método em que rodo minhas threads, é justamente o foreach das dezenas que preciso evitar:

```
    public static void DoWork()
    {
        LFAcertos = new List<Lotofacil>();

        var probabilidades = EnumerableExtentions.Combinations(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 }, 15);
        int acertos = 0;
        int seqI = 0;
        Int16 idMax = LotofacilService.GetMaxConcurso();

        string info = string.Empty;

        if (idMax < LFConcursos.Count)
        {
            for (Int16 i = idMax; i <= LFConcursos.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!idConEmUso.Contains(i) && !LotofacilService.ExistLotofacil(i))
                {
                    info = string.Format("Lendo Concurso {0} em {1}", i, DateTime.Now);
                    Console.WriteLine(info);
                    log.Info(info);
                    idConEmUso.Add(i);

                    seqI = 0;
                    foreach (var seq in probabilidades)
                    {
                        seqI++;
                        acertos = 0;                            

                        foreach (int dezena in seq)
                        {
                            if (LFConcursos.Any(a => a.IdConcurso == i &&
                                  (a.Bola1 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola2 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola3 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola4 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola5 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola6 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola7 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola8 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola9 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola10 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola11 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola12 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola13 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola14 == dezena ||
                                   a.Bola15 == dezena
                                )))
                            {
                                acertos++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (acertos >= 14)
                        {
                            //info = string.Format("{0} acertos encontrados para o concurso {1} em {2}",acertos, i,DateTime.Now);
                            //Console.WriteLine(info);
                            //log.Info(info);
                            LotofacilService.SalvaLotofacil(new Lotofacil
                            {
                                IdConcurso = i,
                                IdSeqProb = seqI,
                                Bola1 = seq.Take(1).Single(),
                                Bola2 = seq.Take(2).Skip(1).Single(),
                                Bola3 = seq.Take(3).Skip(2).Single(),
                                Bola4 = seq.Take(4).Skip(3).Single(),
                                Bola5 = seq.Take(5).Skip(4).Single(),
                                Bola6 = seq.Take(6).Skip(5).Single(),
                                Bola7 = seq.Take(7).Skip(6).Single(),
                                Bola8 = seq.Take(8).Skip(7).Single(),
                                Bola9 = seq.Take(9).Skip(8).Single(),
                                Bola10 = seq.Take(10).Skip(9).Single(),
                                Bola11 = seq.Take(11).Skip(10).Single(),
                                Bola12 = seq.Take(12).Skip(11).Single(),
                                Bola13 = seq.Take(13).Skip(12).Single(),
                                Bola14 = seq.Take(14).Skip(13).Single(),
                                Bola15 = seq.Take(15).Skip(14).Single(),
                                Acertos = acertos
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que você já? Mostre seu código pra gente entender melhor o problema e diga qual sua dúvida específica.

Comment: Amigo não existe possibilidade de fazer isso sem iterar. Até o código mais "simples" possível por trás do que você pode ver fará uma iteração com certeza para obter o resultado que você deseja. Em programação, ainda hoje não existe mágica.

Comment: O que é isso de "collecion de List de objetos"? É uma `List<List<int>>`, `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` ou é outra coisa?

Comment: Bom pessoal, o problema é simples, tenho um List<MinhaClasse> onde, a classe "MinhaClasse" possui diversos atributos, o que preciso é pegar os atributos interios de um determinado índice e transformar em um List<int>

Comment: Seria um movimento ao contrário de um PIVOT, ou seja, que um conjunto de colunas se tranforme numa coluna de n linhas.

Answer (score 0):

Usando linq para altera o foreach das dezenas você pode usar o [COUNT()](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-count/), algo do tipo.

```
acertos = seq.Count(s => (LFConcursos.Any(a => a.IdConcurso == i &&
                                  (a.Bola1 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola2 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola3 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola4 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola5 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola6 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola7 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola8 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola9 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola10 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola11 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola12 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola13 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola14 == s.dezena ||
                                   a.Bola15 == s.dezena
                                ))))
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu quero evitar, penso que deva existir alguma forma forma de fazer isso com o Linq.

Comment: Ceeeerto, user o select do linq, mas não acho que vai ter muita eficiência com isso. https://dotnetfiddle.net/TDg8aQ

Comment: Tenho um conjunto de probabilidades que possui cerca de 3 milhôes de registros sendo que cada índice contém 15 inteiros, pense na demora que está gerando esse foreach rs.